# Add Associated Domain To Expo React-Native Application

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo

I'm trying to add an associated domain to my Expo (non-ejected) react-native project.

My app builds fine and submits through the XCode application loader normally.

But if I add the `associatedDomains` array to my `app.json` I get an error when I try to submit the application:

`ERROR ITMS-90163: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile: 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload/ExpoKitApp.app/ExpoKitApp'."`

I'm not developing this at all within XCode. I've been building the app within my own environment, running `expo build:ios`, downloading the `.ipa` file, opening XCode on a mac, and then running the `Xcode > Open Developer Tools > Application Loader` to submit it to testflight. That process has been working fine, but I'm not sure where in XCode or within my Apple developer account I need to enable the entitlement, if that requires updating some config file, and if so where I put it afterwards.

The expo documentation mentions (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/#universal-links-on-ios) that I need to "To add your domain to the entitlement, click Add (+) at the bottom of the Domains table in order to add a placeholder domain with the webcredentials: prefix. Replace the placeholder with your site’s domain, retaining the prefix." but I don;'t know where my Domains table is. Is that in the apple web interface, or in XCode?

Apologies if the question is a bit basic, or if I'm missing something about the XCode or react-native app development workflow, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out. I had two things going on:

**Renewing Certificates in Expo**

I had to log in to developer.apple.com and delete my keys, profiles, and any other data except for the App ID under https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list

After that, I needed to refresh my certificates within expo by running `expo build:ios -c` which clears the certificates that Expo stores on your servers.

**Invalid App Domain**

Following that, I was getting a different error because the app domain that had listed in `associatedDomains` within `app.json` was `mywebsite.com` rather than the following:

```
{
  expo: {
    ...
    ios: {
      associatedDomains: [
        "applinks:mywebsite.com",
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

After doing that, builds resumed submitting to testflight with the proper entitlements.

Comment: This is now automated with EAS Build, the app.json will be read the the capabilities will be automatically registered to your bundle identifier before the binary is built.

Comment: @EvanBacon can you please provide a source for your comment, I would like to read further, thanks.

Comment: Right here: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/deep-linking/#expo-configuration